# Android Service sending bundle data to activity is NULL

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service, bundle

I am trying to send bundle data from my service to my activity, the url and id is not working only the bitmap, works. I can't figured out why ?

Service class :

```
String imgUrl = ".....img1.jpg";
String imageId = "111";
// Construct pending intent to serve as action for notification item
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePreviewActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("url", imgUrl);
intent.putExtra("id", imageId);
intent.putExtra("bitmap", resizedBitmap);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

ImagePreviewActivity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{

    imgUrl  = extras.getString("url");
    imgId   = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    mBitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");

    Log.i(TAG, "Bundle ->> imgUrl => " + imgUrl + " | imgId => " + imgId);

    //setImageToCarViewFromUrl(imgUrl);
    setImageToCarViewFromBitmap(mBitmap);
}
else if(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap") != null)
{
    mBitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
    setImageToCarViewFromBitmap(mBitmap);
}
else
{
    //Image not Ready
    dialogImagesNotReady(false);
}
```

> > Result : Bundle ->> imgUrl => null | imgId => null
> >
> > > Only mBitmap is working !

Comment: when calling `getActivity` use different requestCode

Answer (score 1):

I think you did put String not a Bundle. You should call

getIntent().getStringExtra("your key");

if you want bundle (value on getIntent().getExtras()), you should put it in a Bundle class

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("key","value");

intent.putExtra("key",bundle)